# Error with Redirects in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I redirect in a post going back to the page that shows the form, JQuery mobile shows me the results instead of the form.

Lets say I have three resources:

```
/ => Just shows a link to the /redirect_to resource, this is to test
/redirect_to => GET: Shows a form to say your name in /thank_you
/redirect_to => POST: Just redirects to /thank_you showing the name that you input
/thank_you => GET: Shows a text "Thank you name!"
```

After I get to the *Thank You!* page, if I try to go back home, and then go to `/redirect_to` I get the content of `/thank_you` instead of the form of `/redirect_to`, if I refresh the page I get the form.

So instead of looking at the form to `redirect_to` I see the `thank_you` page.

Here is the code in **Sinatra** if you don't understand it, at this point I'll re-write it in Flask, Snap, Rails, Django (my app is on Django)... but it should be good enough to read. Here is the code on Github (Since StackOverflow doesn't detect my ruby): https://gist.github.com/1061639

To run the app you basically install sinatra: `gem install sinatra`

And run it: `./jquerymobile_redirect_error.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  <<-end_page
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>JQuery Error</h1>
        <a href="/" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <a href="/" data-icon="delete">Logout</a>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Go to /redirect_to <a href="/redirect_to">here</a>.
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
  end_page
end

get '/redirect_to' do
  <<-end_page
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>JQuery Error</h1>
        <a href="/" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <a href="/" data-icon="delete">Logout</a>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <form action="/redirect_to" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
          <p><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" id="name" placeholder="input your name">
          <p><input type="submit" value="Redirect to /thank_you &rarr;"></p>
        </form>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
  end_page
end

post '/redirect_to' do
  redirect "/thank_you/#{params[:name]}"
end

get '/thank_you/:name' do |name|
  <<-end_page
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>JQuery Error</h1>
        <a href="/" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <a href="/" data-icon="delete">Logout</a>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Thanks #{name}!</h1>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
  end_page
end
```

Comment: Btw, really nice and easy to test code example.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this until the question got "popular" :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Specify `data-url` for your thank_you page. That forces change of url on form submit.

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/thank_you">
```

I found that info from the docs under [Redirects and linking to directories](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html).

> This also allows you to return urls that change as the result of a redirect, for example, you might post a form to "/login.html" but return a page from the url "/account" after a successful submission.

Comment: This answer saved my whole month, THANK YOU! For other people who might be stuck on this, it's generally a good idea to assign the value of request.fullpath to data-url on a master layout page if you have one. For me it probably resolved 5+ bugs at once.