# How can I get django redirect to work when using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, django, redirect, jquery-mobile, django-views

I posted a question earlier about why django redirect was not working correctly, but quickly remove it because I discovered the when I took jquery mobile out of the equation, django is working fine.

I have a form which I am submiting and varifying in django in the usual manner.  This is working fine.  The problem comes when after the form is submited I want to redirect to a different url.

When I do this without jquery mobile, I simply user:

```
response("myurl")
```

which works fine, but When I use jquery mobile I am redirected to the correct page, but the browser url does not change.

This causes all manner of problems because I am using variables in my django url regex, and without the correct url nothing works correctly.

Has anyone else had a similar problem when using jquery mobile and django together? If so what did you do about it? Failing that, can anyone shed any light on why this is happening?

Comment: did you try `HttpResponseRedirect`?

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect had the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of goggling I ended up back at a question on stackoverflow which I had not spotted as it was only tagged as a jquery question and did not mention django in the title either.

[error-with-redirects-in-jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559639/error-with-redirects-in-jquery-mobile)

This suggests specifying data-url to set the url.

In my websites base template file I setup the data-url with a code block marker like this:

```
        <div id="page" name="page" data-role="page" data-url="{% block data-url %}/root/{% endblock %}" class="type-interior">
```

then in the individual page templates I am then able to set to specify the url like this:

```
        {% block data-url %}/root/myurl/{% endblock %}">
```

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution as of course this means that I have to include the data-url block in every template, but it does work

Comment: Why don't you just add `<div data-role="page" data-url="{{ request.get_full_path }}"/>` to the base template? I got it to work like that.