# Response.redirect doesn't change address bar url in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'am using express js to create a web app. In some get requests I redirect user to another page whenever he clicks the link:

```
a( data-icon='home', data-transition='fade', data-role='button', data-theme='a',href='/logout') Home
```

The following code handles the logout:
// app.get('/logout'...)

```
logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

This actually log out the user but address bar url still points to http://localhost:3000/logout . What is wrong with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){ 
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

See more https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L488

Comment: Would you explain what is the difference?

Comment: req.logout(); - what does it mean?

Comment: You didn't explain that you use pasport.js and I gave an example of what works for me in express.js. I can't say quickly what wrong in your case, but see that pasport.js example https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js#L107  maybe it will be helpful

Comment: It seems like a problem with jquery mobile

Comment: Ok, but your question is not about it!

Comment: This solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559639/error-with-redirects-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: Have a similar problem in my case jQuery Mobile was the problem I added this to my form element: data-ajax="false"
(I'm using passport and express too)