# Rails - URL displayed is different from page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, model-view-controller, controller

I'm using mobile_detection on a rails 3 app to serve seperate pages to mobile users. I'm doing my testing through a user agent in Safari. The problem is on one of my processes, rails posts a different URL to the web browser URL bar than the page it is actually loading. So if I refresh the page, it tries to go to the wrong URL it put in the web bar.

Here is the process.

1. User submits Participation form.
2. Participation Controller saves the record, and then renders out either the mobile or html version of Teams#Candidate.

Here is the server log for the process with some of the details excluded.

```
    Started POST "/participations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-20 00:14:37 -0400
    Processing by ParticipationsController#create as HTML
    ...Commits to DB
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/teams/57/candidate
    Started GET "/teams/57/candidate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-20 00:14:37 -0400
    Processing by TeamsController#candidate as HTML
    Rendered teams/candidate.mobile.erb within layouts/application (34.9ms)
```

When I run the same process from desktop, the error does not occur. As as a summer of the problem:

1. Rails does load the teams/candidate.mobile.erb page.
2. However, the URL bar after the page load displays /participations

This does not occur from the desktop.

Below is the Participations Controller. It has somewhat complex logic, but essentially it is detecting if the record has already been created, and doing something different for that case, and for the case of mobile.

def create
    @participation = Participation.new(params[:participation])
    @team = @participation.team

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @participation.save
      if mobile_device?
          format.mobile {redirect_to candidate_team_path(@team), notice: 'You have joined the team!'}
      else
          format.html { redirect_to candidate_team_path(@team), notice: 'You have successfully joined the team.' }
      end        
  else
      if @participation.team_id.nil?
          format.mobile { redirect_to :back, notice: 'No team was joined.' }
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'No team was joined.' }
          format.json { render json: @participation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      else
          if mobile_device?
              format.mobile {redirect_to candidate_team_path(@team), notice: 'Welcome back.'}
          else
              format.html {redirect_to candidate_team_path(@team), notice: 'Welcome back.'}
          end
      end
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Heikki for a great solve.

Hopefully this is helpful for others. The solution was to manually set the URL in the master layout. Given the way JQM uses page caching and page loads internal / external, this is neccessary for certain page loads.

This can be put in application.mobile.erb

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="<% request.fullpath %> "
```

Additional reference:  [Error with Redirects in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559639/error-with-redirects-in-jquery-mobile)