# HttpResponseRedirect not working Django 1.7

Tags: django

I am having a problem with HttpResponseRedirect in Django. It seems that, whatever parameters I try, it either throws an error, or it redirects without changing the URL. I am using it on a custom login_user view, and I want the URL in the address bar to change after they are redirected. If I use redirect instead of HttpResponseRedirect, it does not change. Either way, I can get it to serve the correct template, but the URL stays the same. Being new to Django, it would be helpful if someone could explain to me how to do this and why my current code is not working.
I have seen a couple of similar questions to mine on Stack Exchange, but the answers have not helped.

Here are the relevant parts of my views.py (please note the indenting has gone weird due to copying and pasting in here, and is not the cause of the error).

```
from django.http import *
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def login_user(request):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
        else:
            state = "Your account is not active, please contact the app administrator."
    else:
        state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
state = "Please log in below..."
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'state': state,
    'username': username,
})
return render_to_response('bank/auth.html', {}, context)
```

dashboard is the name of another view, and it works fine in a redirect from my index view. I've also tried hard-coding the url in, but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?? Thanks.

Comment: `HttpResponseRedirect` needs a valid `url` something like (for eg: if you want to redirect to `localhost:8000/` you have to call `HttpResponseRedirect('/')`,

Answer (score 5):

If you use `HttpResponseRedirect`, you must provide the url, not the name of the url.

You can either get the url by using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

or by using the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

If using the either of the above approaches does not work, then there's probably a mistake somewhere else in the view. It's difficult to tell where, since the indentation is incorrect. Try adding some logging or print statements to see if you are really returning the redirect where you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the problem wasn't anything to do with my view code, it was actually a problem caused through using JQuery mobile. I found the answer here: [Error with Redirects in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559639/error-with-redirects-in-jquery-mobile) which was to set the data-url attribute on the page div.
However, I have up-voted Alasdair's answer, as his way is the correct one of the ways I had tried.

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer the simple way as follows:

In **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^dashboard/$', 'appname.views.dashboard_view', name='dashboard_view'),
```

In **views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def dashboard_view(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
```

Comment: Hi Sibtain, URL doesn't change in the browser when we use HttpResponseRedirect() / reverse()/  simple redirect().. what could be the problem ? for more details check out my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085439/render-to-response-or-redirect-changes-the-template-elements-in-django-1-8/